# When to call pipe from the controller when there's a change on the input values?

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a table filled out with data like this :

```
  <tr *ngFor="let row of allData | filterPipe:color:currentDate ">
          <td *ngIf="row != -1">{{row.date| date:'MM/dd/yy'}} </td>
          <td>{{row.Color}}</td>
          <td>{{row.Name}}</td>
```

And I have a pipe that filters based on color and date:

```
  transform(value: any, color: any, currentData: any):any{
      if(color)
            value=value.filter(item=>item.Color==color));
      filter by date
   return value
  }
```

What I want to do, is invoke the pipe from the controller instead of the html, because I need the to have a variable that will hold the filtered data. Because I need to export the filtered data in csv format. In the controller I have a function that does that : `this.allData.forEach((row: MyData) => { csvContent += MyData.toCsv(row) + "\r\n"; });`

So in the component ts I was thinking,after importing it to initalize it like this :

```
    let filterPipe=new FilterPipe();
    this.filteredData=filterPipe.transform(this.allData,this.color,this.currentDate)
```

And then on the html to have :

```
   <tr *ngFor="let row of filteredData">
```

But as i have it, whenever color is chosen ( it's a dropdown value from a ngModel) or currentDate, it invokes the pipe.
Where do I call the pipe in the controller, so that it gets invoked the same way ? 
except that I really need to have access to the filteredData so that I can export it later on.

Or if there's a way to bind the filtered data after it's returned, to the controller so that I have that as an object in the controller for exporting.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Edit:

Initially I want to have a default filter, that filters data where date=now.
That data will be sliced 10 and added more in scrolling as needed.
Then user can choose to filter based on a color and change the date.

So if I have a function

```
filterByDate(date:any){
this.filteredData=this.allData.filter... where date=date
}

filterByColor(color:string)
{
this.filteredData=this.allData.filter where color=color;
}
```

and I bind the ngModel of the dropdown and the input field of both.
How do I manage it without breaking the flow that i had?
How do I make it that what's returned on ngOnInit is first filtered for todays date, then displayed?

When I had it on the html, on the pipe function I had an if(startDate empty) then default filter for moment(). Else filter for startDate.

Comment: _"invoke the pipe from the controller instead of the html":_ pipes are only used in templates because they are purely _presentational_. This may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so why do you need a variable in the controller that will contain the filtered data?

Comment: I get allData from a service, and I return it on ngOnInit, and then on the table I filter it.
But I need to export the filtered data in csv format.
In the controller I have a function that does that :

` this.allData.forEach((row: MyData) => {
      csvContent += MyData.toCsv(row) + "\r\n"; 
    }); `

And I need allData to be the filtered data. :|

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I've added it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Pipes are purely presentational and can not mutate their data source, I would suggest filtering entirely in the Component.

First, implement your filtering function in the Component, like

```
filterList(color: string) {
  this.filteredData = this.allData.filter(item => item.Color === color);
}
```

Not forgetting that when you make your service call to get `allData` the first time, you also set `filteredData` to the full list.

Then, just bind your filter function to an [`(ngModelChange)`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inside-ngmodel) event of your filter dropdown (something like `(ngModelChange)="filterList($event.target.value)"`) so that when you change the drop-down it will run your filter.

Then just always display the filtered data: `<tr *ngFor="let row of filteredData">` and change detection will update the list for you when `filteredData` changes.

#### EDIT

Since you need to show only 10 rows of data, you could write a second utility function, store the cursor position, slice and return the desired window:

```
cursor: number = 0;

function onScroll(down: boolean) {
  // Slice your array
  this.windowData = this.filteredData.slice(this.cursor,
    down ? this.cursor + 10 : this.cursor - 10);

  // Update the cursor to your new position
  this.cursor = down ? this.cursor + 10 : this.cursor - 10;
}
```

And instead show `windowData` in your `*ngFor`, also remembering to set the first `windowData` on load.

Comment: Thank you so much. But also, I slice the object I show, 10 rows at a time.
So everytime I push into the allData array,10 more onScroll, should I do the same with filteredData ?
So that it has those values to filter from ?

Comment: @JenPen Updated. If the answer was useful you can up-vote it. If it solved your problem you can click the checkmark. Otherwise, keep commenting :)

Comment: It was very helpful, but now it got confusing haha.
The onScroll function is what ngx-infinite-scroll calls.
What I have so far is :
on ngOnInit - slice displayedData , and show only 10.
on onScroll- get length of displayedData. 
And length of all data returned by service.
if displayedData is smaller, then push 10 more from allData to displayedData.

I was asking now that I'm returning filteredData.Should I make filteredData=displayedData when slicing?
But thank you !! I'll try it right away your way :)

Comment: @JenPen I was just providing illustrative patterns based on what I could glean from the question. You don't need to specifically use my scroll function. The idea was just that you could use three lists: main, filtered, window. If ngx-scroll (I don't know it) manages the window (sliced data) all the better, just pass `filteredData` to it. Probably.

Comment: Ah thanks. I edited the question that explains what part of moving the filtering from the pipe to the controller in separate functions confused me. 
But I will mark your answer as correct, as it did answer my initial question

Comment: @JenPen Cool. I hope it was helpful. If you come up with a better solution, do feel free to post that as an answer as well.